# Issue with PowerShell ConvertTo-Json adding un-printable characters to beginning of file

Tags: powershell, convertto-json

I am having a problem with a PowerShell ConvertTo-Json command. The resulting file has two non-printable characters as the first to characters of the file. Using Format-Hex, the return values are:

```
           00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F

00000000   FF FE 5B 00 0D 00 0A 00 20 00 20 00 20 00 20 00  .þ[..... . . . .
00000010   7B 00 0D 00 0A 00 20 00 20 00 20 00 20 00 20 00  {..... . . . . .
...
```

The bad characters are the FF and FE in the 00 and 01 positions.  The command I am using to generate the file is the following:

```
$search.resources.attributes |select $Object.Attributes.ID  |Sort-Object -Property displayname | ConvertTo-Json | Out-File  ([Environment]::GetFolderPath("Desktop")+"\RL_Identities.json")
```

The $search is a result of an Invoke-RestMethod call.

I am importing this file into an Oracle CLOB column. This column has a CHECK (COLUMN_NAME IS JSON) check constraint and it fails with the two un-printable characters in the file. If I open the file in Notepad++, do a select all and copy/paste to a new file, the new file loads perfectly because it doesn't have the two characters at the beginning.

Is there any reason the two characters are there? Is it "feature" of the ConvertTo-Json command or could it be coming from the data in the Invoke-RestMethod call? If there is no way to prevent these characters from being there, is there a way to programmatically remove the first two bytes of the file?

Comment: Out-file defaults to utf16 encoding.  FF FE is the encoding sig or BOM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Your file uses the "Unicode" (UTF-16LE) character encoding**, which is what you get by default in Windows PowerShell when you use `>` / `Out-File`.

- The first two bytes, `FF` and `FE`, make up the so-called [BOM (byte-order mark)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark), aka Unicode signature, which identifies the encoding.

Instead, use [`Set-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-content) (or `-Out-File`) with the `-Encoding` parameter to specify the desired encoding.

The caveat is that if you need UTF-8, `-Encoding utf8` in Windows PowerShell creates UTF-8 files *with a BOM*, which not all consumers understand.

- In **[*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md)**, by contrast, you get **BOM-*less* UTF-8 *by default***, across all cmdlets (and therefore also with `>`).

**If you're on *Windows PowerShell* and need to create a BOM-*less* UTF-8 file**, you can use the following workaround via [`New-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/new-item):

```bash
# Creates out.txt with BOM-less UTF-8 encoding.
# Note that the -Value argument must be a single, potentially multi-line
# string and a trailing newline is NOT added.
$null = New-Item -Force out.txt -Value (
          ConvertTo-Json 'hü'
        )
```

The sample `ConvertTo-Json` call results in verbatim `"hü"`. Passing the resulting file to [`Format-Hex`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/format-hex) shows that the file has *no* BOM and that `ü` (LATIN SMALL LETTER U WITH DIAERESIS, [`U+00FC`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/fc)) is correctly encoded as UTF-8 byte sequence `0xC3`, `0xBC`:

```
           Path: C:\Users\jdoe\out.txt

           00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F

00000000   22 68 C3 BC 22                                   "hÃ¼"
```